# Bash quotes expansion

Tags: bash

I want to execute a command in a `bash` script which has this style:

```
rdiff-backup --verbosity 5 -somearguments -somemorearguments \
    --remote-schema 'ssh -i $keyfile -C %s' \
    sourcedir backup::/targetdir
```

The problem appears with the `--remote-schema` argument. I have to make the *ssh-key* variable, in this example with `$keyfile`.

I construct the resulting command in `$rdiffcmd`. I do not have a problem to construct a command where everything looks like it should work: An `echo $rdiffcmd` shows the necessary quotes around `--remote-schema`. But there has to be an invisible expansion because I always get the message that `rdiff-backup` (on the local side) does not understand `-i`. So it is not using the quotes.

What do I have to do to group the remote-schema together and make it look like one argument?

Very strange: I can paste and copy the output of `echo $rdiffcmd` in a terminal and it works. But as `$rdiffcmd` in my script it does not with the above problem.

Comment: Use double quotes. " vs '. Single quotes are literals, variables within are not expanded. Here's how bash handles the various expansions: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Thanks. By the way: Is there a possibility to group an argument inside the argument? I now need to give a directory-name also. But directory names can contain spaces. As remote-schema is already encapsulated with " the additional " around the directory name seems not to have the wanted result.

Comment: Escape characters with backslashes. e.g. " \"quoted within quotes\" ". The first expansion will happen on the local side, removing the outer quotes then the escaped quotes will be removed on the remote side.

Comment: @css1971 That doesn't work if the ‘quoted within quotes’ bit can itself contain quotes. user2715068 : it's tricky. Edit your question to add some sample code that works without special characters so that we know exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If `$keyfile` contains spaces and whatnot:

```
rdiff-backup --verbosity 5 -somearguments -somemorearguments \
    --remote-schema 'ssh -i "'"$keyfile"'" -C %s' \
    sourcedir backup::/targetdir
```